# Metricbeat is unable to send data to Elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssl, metricbeat

I have setup successfully local Elasticsearch and Kibana version 8.8 via docker compose from this [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) and it works perfectly. I can access to Elasticsearch via https://localhost:9200 and Kibana via http://localhost:5601. Now, I need to setup Metricbeat to collect host system information, however I could not see anything collected. Below are the output after running the command `metricbeat test output`, the `metricbeat.yml` file as well as logs from Metricbeat.

1. metricbeat test output

```
elasticsearch: https://localhost:9200...
  parse url... OK
  connection...
    parse host... OK
    dns lookup... OK
    addresses: ::1, 127.0.0.1
    dial up... OK
  TLS...
    security: server's certificate chain verification is enabled
    handshake... OK
    TLS version: TLSv1.3
    dial up... OK
  talk to server... OK
  version: 8.7.1
```

2. metricbeat.yml file

```
###################### Metricbeat Configuration Example #######################

# This file is an example configuration file highlighting only the most common
# options. The metricbeat.reference.yml file from the same directory contains all the
# supported options with more comments. You can use it as a reference.
#
# You can find the full configuration reference here:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/index.html

# =========================== Modules configuration ============================

metricbeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: true

  # Period on which files under path should be checked for changes
  reload.period: 30s

# ======================= Elasticsearch template setting =======================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: false


# ================================== General ===================================

# The name of the shipper that publishes the network data. It can be used to group
# all the transactions sent by a single shipper in the web interface.
#name:

# The tags of the shipper are included in their own field with each
# transaction published.
#tags: ["service-X", "web-tier"]

# Optional fields that you can specify to add additional information to the
# output.
#fields:
#  env: staging

# ================================= Dashboards =================================
# These settings control loading the sample dashboards to the Kibana index. Loading
# the dashboards is disabled by default and can be enabled either by setting the
# options here or by using the `setup` command.
#setup.dashboards.enabled: false

# The URL from where to download the dashboards archive. By default this URL
# has a value which is computed based on the Beat name and version. For released
# versions, this URL points to the dashboard archive on the artifacts.elastic.co
# website.
#setup.dashboards.url:

# =================================== Kibana ===================================

# Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
setup.kibana:

  # Kibana Host
  # Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 5601)
  # In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:5601/path
  # IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:5601
  host: "localhost:5601"
  protocol: "http"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "*********"  
  # Kibana Space ID
  # ID of the Kibana Space into which the dashboards should be loaded. By default,
  # the Default Space will be used.
  #space.id:

# =============================== Elastic Cloud ================================

# These settings simplify using Metricbeat with the Elastic Cloud (https://cloud.elastic.co/).

# The cloud.id setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.hosts` and
# `setup.kibana.host` options.
# You can find the `cloud.id` in the Elastic Cloud web UI.
#cloud.id:

# The cloud.auth setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.username` and
# `output.elasticsearch.password` settings. The format is `<user>:<pass>`.
#cloud.auth:

# ================================== Outputs ===================================

# Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.

# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

  # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
  protocol: "https"

  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  #api_key: "id:api_key"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "*******"
  ssl.certificate: "C:/Users/thanhpn.ETC/Downloads/certs/es01/es01.crt"
  ssl.key: "C:/Users/thanhpn.ETC/Downloads/certs/es01/es01.key"
  ssl.certificate_authorities: ["C:/Users/thanhpn.ETC/Downloads/ca/ca.crt"]  

# ------------------------------ Logstash Output -------------------------------
#output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  #hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"

# ================================= Processors =================================

# Configure processors to enhance or manipulate events generated by the beat.

processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~


# ================================== Logging ===================================

# Sets log level. The default log level is info.
# Available log levels are: error, warning, info, debug
#logging.level: debug

# At debug level, you can selectively enable logging only for some components.
# To enable all selectors use ["*"]. Examples of other selectors are "beat",
# "publisher", "service".
#logging.selectors: ["*"]

# ============================= X-Pack Monitoring ==============================
# Metricbeat can export internal metrics to a central Elasticsearch monitoring
# cluster.  This requires xpack monitoring to be enabled in Elasticsearch.  The
# reporting is disabled by default.

# Set to true to enable the monitoring reporter.
#monitoring.enabled: false

# Sets the UUID of the Elasticsearch cluster under which monitoring data for this
# Metricbeat instance will appear in the Stack Monitoring UI. If output.elasticsearch
# is enabled, the UUID is derived from the Elasticsearch cluster referenced by output.elasticsearch.
#monitoring.cluster_uuid:

# Uncomment to send the metrics to Elasticsearch. Most settings from the
# Elasticsearch output are accepted here as well.
# Note that the settings should point to your Elasticsearch *monitoring* cluster.
# Any setting that is not set is automatically inherited from the Elasticsearch
# output configuration, so if you have the Elasticsearch output configured such
# that it is pointing to your Elasticsearch monitoring cluster, you can simply
# uncomment the following line.
#monitoring.elasticsearch:

# ============================== Instrumentation ===============================

# Instrumentation support for the metricbeat.
#instrumentation:
    # Set to true to enable instrumentation of metricbeat.
    #enabled: false

    # Environment in which metricbeat is running on (eg: staging, production, etc.)
    #environment: ""

    # APM Server hosts to report instrumentation results to.
    #hosts:
    #  - http://localhost:8200

    # API Key for the APM Server(s).
    # If api_key is set then secret_token will be ignored.
    #api_key:

    # Secret token for the APM Server(s).
    #secret_token:


# ================================= Migration ==================================

# This allows to enable 6.7 migration aliases
#migration.6_to_7.enabled: true
```

3. metricbeat logs (metricbeat-20230603-9.ndjson)

```
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-06-03T12:37:25.322+0700","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":779},"message":"Home path: [C:\\Program Files\\Elastic\\Beats\\8.8.0\\metricbeat] Config path: [C:\\ProgramData\\Elastic\\Beats\\metricbeat] Data path: [C:\\ProgramData\\Elastic\\Beats\\metricbeat\\data] Logs path: [C:\\ProgramData\\Elastic\\Beats\\metricbeat\\logs]","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-06-03T12:37:25.323+0700","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":787},"message":"Beat ID: 3cb5f551-4976-49b5-bd42-47990f82355c","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"warn","@timestamp":"2023-06-03T12:37:25.472+0700","log.logger":"add_cloud_metadata","log.origin":{"file.name":"add_cloud_metadata/provider_aws_ec2.go","file.line":81},"message":"read token request for getting IMDSv2 token returns empty: Put \"http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token\": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connectex: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.. No token in the metadata request will be used.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-06-03T12:37:25.473+0700","log.logger":"add_cloud_metadata","log.origin":{"file.name":"add_cloud_metadata/add_cloud_metadata.go","file.line":100},"message":"add_cloud_metadata: hosting provider type not detected.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"warn","@timestamp":"2023-06-03T12:37:25.473+0700","log.logger":"cfgwarn","log.origin":{"file.name":"tlscommon/config.go","file.line":102},"message":"DEPRECATED: Treating the CommonName field on X.509 certificates as a host name when no Subject Alternative Names are present is going to be removed. Please update your certificates if needed. Will be removed in version: 8.0.0","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-06-03T12:37:25.473+0700","log.logger":"esclientleg","log.origin":{"file.name":"eslegclient/connection.go","file.line":108},"message":"elasticsearch url: https://localhost:9200","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-06-03T12:37:25.491+0700","log.logger":"esclientleg","log.origin":{"file.name":"eslegclient/connection.go","file.line":291},"message":"Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 8.7.1","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
```

Yes I noticed that in the logs its complaining about this `DEPRECATED: Treating the CommonName field on X.509 certificates as a host name when no Subject Alternative Names are present is going to be removed. Please update your certificates if needed. Will be removed in version: 8.0.0`, however I'm not sure how to fix it. Tried to use the `elasticsearch-certutil` to regenerate the CA but did not work, got some error as below:

I ran this command line:

```
elasticsearch-certutil cert --pem --silent --in C:\Users\thanhpn.ETC\Downloads\instances.yml --out certs.zip --ca elastic-stack-ca.p12
```

and got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: elastic-stack-ca.p12
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:234)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:379)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:431)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:422)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.ssl.KeyStoreUtil.readKeyStore(KeyStoreUtil.java:71)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.CertParsingUtils.readKeyPairsFromKeystore(CertParsingUtils.java:105)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.CertParsingUtils.readPkcs12KeyPairs(CertParsingUtils.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.CertificateTool$CertificateCommand.lambda$loadPkcs12CA$1(CertificateTool.java:366)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.CertificateTool.withPassword(CertificateTool.java:1027)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.CertificateTool$CertificateCommand.loadPkcs12CA(CertificateTool.java:361)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.CertificateTool$CertificateCommand.getCAInfo(CertificateTool.java:347)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.CertificateTool$GenerateCertificateCommand.getCAInfo(CertificateTool.java:759)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.CertificateTool$GenerateCertificateCommand.execute(CertificateTool.java:701)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:94)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.CertificateTool.execute(CertificateTool.java:160)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64)
```